# How to connect Ms Access Db using php

Tags: php, ms-access

I want to connect Ms Access Database using php, so i have write a code like below, but i am getting error like this,

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state
>   IM002 in SQLConnect

I am using Php 5.6.38 and already installed a driver for ODBC.

Here below is my code, Please do needful.

Thanks in advance.

```
$db = realpath('import\ssr.mdb');
if(!file_exists($db)){
    die('Error finding access database');
}
// Connection to ms access
$conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=".$db.";Uid=; Pwd=;");
print_r($conn); die();
```